# Exchange Management Powershell with .Net

Tags: .net, powershell

Why am I receiving this Exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term new-storagegroup....
```

Relevant code:

```
RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
myRunSpace.Open();

//Create pipeline and feed it the script text
Pipeline pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

string strScript = "new-storagegroup -Server KINGKONG"
    + " -LogFolderPath c:\\rsg\\logs -Name RecoveryGroup -SystemFolderPath c:\\rsg\\data -Recovery";

//Create an instance of the Command class by using the name of the cmdlet that you want to run
Command myCommand = new Command(strScript);

//Add the command to the Commands collection of the pipeline.
pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pipeline.Commands.AddScript(strScript)` instead. A `Command` object expects only the Cmdlet, e.g. "New-StorageGroup" alone. You would then use the returned `Command` object's `Parameters` collection to add the parameters.

Comment: I tried using the AddScript instead for a `New-Mailbox` command and that doesn't work. I'm guessing I'm going to have to go through all the parameters one by one. Have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using that command with parameters (`New-Mailbox`) and I'm getting pretty close to the same error as him (just with `New-Mailbox` instead of the command he's running). I used `pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script)` and I still get that error. I'm thinking I have to use a something like `var cmd = new Command(script, true);` the use `cmd.Parameters.Add("key", "value");` - Any suggestions on that. I haven't resolved it yet, but that was going to be my next try.

Comment: Have you ensure that the exchange module is loaded first? Are you using powershell 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using powershell 2 and I'm using this command first `pipeline.Commands.AddScript("add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 ;");` then I'm doing the `New-Mailbox` like this `var cmd = new Command("New-Mailbox", true);` After that, I'm adding everything as a parameter (for instance "-UserPrincipalName" and stuff like that. It looks like it's not registering the snap-in. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, is there a way to verify which version of powershell it's running?

Comment: I figured this out by using `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and verified it's v2